# PyQt5 QWidget doesn't show up when called in @classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to call a `QWidget()` within a `@classmethod` to obtain the parameters for the class from a Qt form:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
import sys


class FormDialog(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        super(FormDialog, self).__init__()

        print("FormDialog called")


class Files(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def from_gui(cls):
        form = FormDialog()
        form.show()

        return cls()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    obj = Files.from_gui()  # "FormDialog called" appears, but window doesn't show up

    form = FormDialog()  # "FormDialog called" appears
    form.show()  # Window appears

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I call the `FormDialog()` within the `@classmethod`, the window doesn't show up. If I call it outside of the `@classmethod`, everything works like intended. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this method in the FormDialog class to see what is really happen

```
def __del__(self):
    print('Deleting the form')
```

The formDialog is destroyed when the from_gui method return.

You can solve it with :

1. returning the form outside the from_gui, so it can live out of from_gui scope
2. Make FormDialog inherit QDialog instead of QWidget and use exec instead of show, this way the dialog shows and blocks, next instruction will be executed after the dialog is destroyed